# Is it possible to send mail from localhost using php with the help of gmail...?

Tags: php, email

Is it possible to send mail from localhost using php with the help of gmail...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need an SMTP client like PHPMailer.

http://mediakey.dk/~cc/send-email-using-php-phpmailer-and-gmail/